# chain array operations in PHP

Tags: php, perl, list, lambda

How would I chain operations to work on lists in PHP ?

In Perl, I can write

```
print join "\n", map {$_ .= '<td>'.$_.'</td>'} sort get_array_from_db();
```

Are there efficient constructions in modern PHP? I read about `array_map` but it is a normal function and is not very powerful.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to be more explicit with php, and make your own sort function which actually *returns* sorted array.

```
<?php

function get_sorted ($arr) {

  sort($arr);
  return $arr;
}

function get_array_from_db () {

  return array(7,5,3,2,9);
}

print join("\n", array_map(function($_){ return "<td>$_</td>"; }, get_sorted(get_array_from_db())
));
```

Comment: Using plain foreach in php makes more sense `foreach ($arr as &$v) $v = "<td>$v</td>"; unset($v); ...`

Comment: @ialarmedalien besides being shorter to type, `join` is more common among languages; http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php

Comment: Can't believe I hadn't noticed `join` before now!! why do so many people use `implode` in their PHP scripts?

Comment: @ialarmedalien I believe the reason is that join is introduced later in php than [`implode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_collapse). `:)`

Comment: Because the base function name `implode()` is less likely to change in the future than the alias `join()`.